# R Notebook is saving but I receive an unexpected symbol error without any resolution

Tags: r, syntax-error, rnotebook

I am receiving an error when saving my R Notebook (.Rmd) file in R Studio. The notebook seems to be saving correctly but I can't figure out what is causing the error and if there is an impact of the error.

I have tried changing formatting and syntax. Nothing seems to correct it. When I remove the line of code, it picks a new line and says there is an unexpected symbol there instead.

Similar questions on stack have suggested that the problem may be the text lying in a code chunk, but my text is not in a code chunk.

**Update:** I am thinking this might be some sort of system or settings issue because it seems the error occurs no matter what is in my R Notebook.

Reproducible example:

```
---
title: "example"
output: html_notebook
---

## Sample Header
Line of text
```

Output when saving the .Rmd file:

```
> source("C:/Users/USER/Folder/notebook.Rmd")
Error in source("C:/Users/USER/Folder/notebook.Rmd") : 
  C:/Users/USER/Folder/notebook.Rmd:7:6: unexpected symbol
6: ## Sample Header
7: Line of
        ^
```

Comment: My guess is that it's a line before that one with an unclosed parenthesis, danging comma, mismatched curly brace, etc.

Comment: This was my first thought too but it doesn't appear to be the case. The line producing the errors is only the second line after the YAML closing --- and the line before it is just a header line that says # Section 1

Comment: Can you delete sections before (and after) that line (but still generating the error) so you can share a minimal reproducible example?

Comment: @Brian I have updated the question with an example. Thanks!

Comment: You said this is happening when you save the .Rmd file, do you know why it's calling `source` instead of `knit`? `source` is for .R files, not .Rmd files.

Comment: Hmm... no I am not sure why it would be calling source. I created the .Rmd file within R studio and it is the only file open within my environment at the moment. No scripts are currently open. Could it be because I have the output set to output: html_notebook ?